# LWJGL Collision Detection

Tags: collision-detection, lwjgl

I cannot find LWJGL collision detection with a camera and walls. Like making it to where you can not walk through walls and other different shaped rectangular prisms and cubes. How do I set up LWJGL collision?

Comment: Help! JBullet doesn't work, Ode4j doesn't work for me, what should I use?!?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

LWJGL does not have a physics library built in to it. If you want to add collision detection to LWJGL, you'll need to create the collision detection yourself or use an existing library to add physics and collision detection to your game.

Comment: No, I mean how do I program it or add it?

Comment: How to program it is too broad of a question for this site. Adding it can be done with an existing physics library. Choosing which one to use is up to you.

Comment: No, I said 'how do I program it or _add it_', meaning if I can't program it, how to add it? I tried JBullet, but what I did it seemed outdated.

Comment: Yes, I replied to your "add it" comment as well. You do that with an existing physics library. The steps to add it will depend on the physics library you choose. There are typically "Hello World" or similar getting started tutorials with physics libraries. I suggest you choose a physics library that works for you and follow the tutorial for that library.

Comment: My question: Which one is updated and best for me? I use Java and LWJGL, and Slick-Util for Texture Loading,  although that shouldn't matter. But what is a good Java library?

Comment: As I said, choosing which one to use is up to you. Which technology to use questions are off topic for this site. They don't have a correct answer and are primarily opinion based. I suggest you try one of the sites listed at the bottom of [this page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you want to find somewhere to ask that question.